# information about related models in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, model, restful-architecture

Hello I´m writing an API and I want to display more information about the related model.

**Routes.php**

```
Route::resource('makes', 'MakesController');
```

**MakesController.php**

```
class MakesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = Make::all();
        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

This returns only information about the makes (id, name)
but how can I display also how many models has each make?

**I have defined these two models**

```
class Make extends Model
{
    public function models()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CarModel');
    }
}


class CarModel extends Model
{
    public function make()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Make');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `$visible` field in the `Make` model's class like this:

```
protected $visible = ['models'];
```

This will automatically appends the related model's array to `array`/`json`.

You can also use an optional way with `makeVisible` method:

```
class MakesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = Make::all();
        return response()->makeVisible('models')->json($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I´m getting Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getModelsAttribute()

Comment: Maybe try with the `$visible` field instaed of `$appends`.

Comment: nice! is there a way to make it optional? Ie. sending an extra parameter in the url to append it or not?

Comment: Sure. You can use `makeVisible` method. I'll reedit my entry